# Start service before user logs in

Tags: debian, systemd, services

I'm running a debian 4.8.4-1 x64 vanilla on a VirtualBox VM on a Win 7 x64 host. Purpose of the installation is to serve as a server for the subsonic music streaming service, which offers a webinterface on port 4040. The service runs as user 'subsonic', which is a standard user which can login, and has a home dir (not sure if this matters.)

When I start the VM from the windows host, the machine boots up and gives me a login prompt. At this point, I can access the apache webserver on port 80 from other machines, but I cannot access the subsonic service on port 4040. As soon as I login the subsonic user, the subsonic service is available.

Obviously, the subsonic service is only started after the user logs in, while apache starts before the login. What is the difference, and how do I set the subsonic service to start up before login? Is this even the right approach, or should I log in the user automatically instead?

I'm looking for a way that works, and preferrably is idiomatic to the linux philosophy.

Comment: Where is the service file that starts this service located? If it's in any user directory mentioned in `systemd.unit(5)`, then the service will start _after_ the user logs in.

Comment: Thank you! I tried googling but I can't put the pieces together yet. How do I check that, and how do I change it - just move the service file? At what point are these service files created? By default the service runs as root, I changed that, but I did not change any service files...

Comment: How did you install subsonic and how did you configure it to start automatically?

Comment: I installed the deb-package with dpkg. The config in /etc/default/subsonic allows to specify a user to run the service. The startup file in /etc/init.d/ parses that file and starts the service with that user via start-stop-daemon.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the service's name is `subsonic`, If you run `systemctl status subsonic.service` and there are no errors, then the `subsonic` service is being run as a system service, in which case this answer won't help much.

However, if you get an error there, but instead run `systemctl --user status subsonic.service` and have no errors, then that means that the service is being run under the user's instance of `systemd`, and the first line of the output indicates where the service file is being stored. This means that, for the service to start, the user would first have to log in.

If you want to make the service run for all users, regardless of whether the actual user is logged in or not, then move the service file to `/etc/systemd/system` (see `man systemd.unit` for the list of system paths). Additionally, if you want to have the service run under a particular user (and not under `root`), you'll want to add `User=subsonic` to the `[Service]` section of the file (see `man systemd.service`).

After moving this file, running `systemctl status subsonic.service` should result in some output (probably that the service is inactive, but loaded), and running `systemctl --user status subsonic.service` should result in an error.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! It looks like the subsonic service runs as a system service. systemctl status tells me that ExecPath=/etc/init.d/subsonic, so could this have something to do with the recent switch of the init systems? In comparison, apache2 lies in /etc/init.d/ as well, and apache becomes accessible without login. So I expect there will be another file that tells systemd when to start what. Could you point me to that please? Thanks!

Comment: So the startup script is an `init` script. systemd automatically makes a conversion of that script to a systemd `service` file. To see this conversion, run `systemctl cat subsonic`.

Comment: Great, I think I'm closing in on the issue. Comparing the service output (via cat) tells me that apache2 has SysVStartPriority=2, while subsonic has SysVStartPriority=3. I checked the init scripts of both, and can't find any parameter that might result in this difference. Do you know where to find this? Thank you, and sorry for these noob questions. I've never bothered to work  with the services on a linux machine before.

Comment: I actually haven't seen that property until now, and based on [this](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-November/025729.html), that property is now ignored. If I had to take a guess, though, it's the number that's in the name of the `init` script file located in `/etc/rc3.d/`.